# Redirect user to login form if the user is not logged in

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I made a web app and deployed it to firebase. Let's say that the link is `https://firebasewebapp`. When I open the link the `Sign In` form shows up but when I open `https://firebasewebapp/#/home` I get redirected to the `home page` even if the user is not logged in. Is there a way to redirect the user if it's not `logged in`? I use `Flutter 2.10.3 Stable Channel`

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: options),
  );
  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
  ], child: const MyApp()));
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Portalul e-Radauti',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
        textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor:
                MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.orange),
            foregroundColor:
                MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      initialRoute: '/login',
      routes: {
        '/home': (_) => const MyHomePage(),
        '/addcouncilmember': (_) => const LocalCouncilLayout(),
        '/signup': (_) => const SignUp(),
        '/login': (_) => const LogIn(),
        '/addevent': (_) => const AddEventLayout(),
        '/profile': (_) => const Profile(),
      },
      //   home: const MyApp(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. How to accomplish it will depend on how you have configured your app. You will need to share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have for the community to give you details on how you could approach the solution.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this would be to use [Flutter's Navigator 2.0](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/route-navigator-refactoring) or a package which wrap Navigator 2.0's API such as [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) or [beamer](https://pub.dev/packages/beamer).

Here's an example of how you can implement this behavior by using go_router:

### router.dart

```dart
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

import 'app.dart';
import 'redirection/log_in.dart';
import 'redirection/my_home_page.dart';
import 'redirection/sign_up.dart';

GoRouter routerGenerator(LoggedInStateInfo loggedInState) {
  return GoRouter(
    initialLocation: Routes.login,
    refreshListenable: loggedInState,
    redirect: (state) {
      final isOnLogin = state.location == Routes.login;
      final isOnSignUp = state.location == Routes.signup;
      final isLoggedIn = loggedInState.isLoggedIn;

      if (!isOnLogin && !isOnSignUp && !isLoggedIn) return Routes.login;
      if ((isOnLogin || isOnSignUp) && isLoggedIn) return Routes.home;
      return null;
    },
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: Routes.home,
        builder: (_, __) => const MyHomePage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: Routes.login,
        builder: (_, __) => LogIn(loggedInState),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: Routes.signup,
        builder: (_, __) => SignUp(loggedInState),
      ),
    ],
  );
}

abstract class Routes {
  static const home = '/home';
  static const signup = '/signup';
  static const login = '/login';
}
```

### app.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'router.dart';

class LoggedInStateInfo extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isLoggedIn = false;
  bool get isLoggedIn => _isLoggedIn;

  void login() {
    _isLoggedIn = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _loggedInStateInfo = LoggedInStateInfo();

  late final _router = routerGenerator(_loggedInStateInfo);

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _loggedInStateInfo.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routeInformationParser: _router.routeInformationParser,
      routerDelegate: _router.routerDelegate,
    );
  }
}
```

With this code you only need to update the value of `_isLoggedIn` inside the `LoggedInStateInfo` and notify the listeners to access the `HomePage`, otherwise you will only have access to the `LogIn` and `SignUp` pages even when you manually change the URL.

### Bonus

#### `LogIn` page code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

import '../app.dart';
import '../router.dart';

class LogIn extends StatelessWidget {
  final LoggedInStateInfo loggedInStateInfo;

  const LogIn(this.loggedInStateInfo, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('LogIn')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: loggedInStateInfo.login,
              child: const Text('Log In'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => context.push(Routes.signup),
              child: const Text('Sign Up'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### `SignUp` page code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../app.dart';

class SignUp extends StatelessWidget {
  final LoggedInStateInfo loggedInStateInfo;

  const SignUp(this.loggedInStateInfo, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('SignUp')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: loggedInStateInfo.login,
          child: const Text('Sign Up'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but right now I try to refactor the code from using Provider to GetX. But I'll give this one a try !

Comment: @t3nsa, yeah the implementation will depend on which package you'll use to manage your navigation. I choose to show an example with go_router because it will soon be directly integrated inside the Flutter SDK as the default wrapper of Navigator 2.