# Redirecting issue using go_router package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am implementing a feature on flutter web where if a user isn't logged in, he will redirect to the login page. I am using go_router for this functionality. So far I've implemented all the logic according to this link but I am stuck at one point i.e even when I successfully logged in, authState.isLoggedIn property in the redirect method of GoRouter is still false. Can someone guide me to where I am doing wrong? Below is the code:

GoRouter:

```
GoRouter routerGenerator(AuthProvider authState) {
  return GoRouter(
    initialLocation: Routes.login,
    refreshListenable: authState,
    redirect: (state) {
      final isOnLogin = state.location == Routes.login;
      final isOnSignUp = state.location == Routes.signup;
      final isLoggedIn = authState.isLoggedIn; //this is false

      if (!isOnLogin && !isOnSignUp && !isLoggedIn) return Routes.login;
      if ((isOnLogin || isOnSignUp) && isLoggedIn) return Routes.home;
      return null;
    },
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        name: Routes.home,
        path: '/Dashboard',
        pageBuilder: (context, state) => MaterialPage<void>(
          key: state.pageKey,
          child: Home(),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Authstate class:

```
class AuthProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isLoggedIn = false;
  bool get isLoggedIn => _isLoggedIn;

  set loggedIn(bool value) {
    _isLoggedIn = value;
  }
  
  ApiBaseHelper _helper = ApiBaseHelper();

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> login(String email, String password) async {
 
      var response = await _helper.post('Authentication/Login', 
               new LoginVM(username: email, password: password, otp: ''));

      this.loggedIn = true;

      notifyListeners();

      return response;
  }
}
```

The link I am following:
[Redirect user to login form if the user is not logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71753076/redirect-user-to-login-form-if-the-user-is-not-logged-in)